# Plane region bounded by an ellipse.

Tags: calculus

I was able to solve this problema from Swokowski Calculus with Analytic Geometry of but I think I made two mistakes to achieve it.

"The base of a solid is a plane region bounded by an ellipse with major and minor axes lengths 16 and 9, respectively. Find the volume of the solid if every cross section by a plane perpendicular to  major axis is (a) a square; (b) and equilateral triangle."

It's about (a):

This is how I got the function
$$\frac{x^2}{16^2} + \frac{y^2}{9^2} = 1$$
$$y^2 = 1 - \frac{81x^2}{256} $$

The integral

$$ \int  1 - \frac{81x^2}{256} x dx$$
from 0 to 16 I gave me the correct answer 864, but I don't understand why it's not 4 times it.

The square is bounded by the ellipse so it's sides must be $2y$ and the area $4y^2$.

This is how I pictured it [image]

Is my equation wrong or me interpretation of the square?

Comment: $y^2 = 1 - \frac{81x^2}{256}$ isn't correct.

Comment: Please give full reference to the Swokowski book, in particular its title (a same author often publishes several books).

Comment: @JeanMarie Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the major axis is $16$ and minor axis is $9$ which means $\small 2a = 16, 2b = 9 \implies a = 8, b = \displaystyle \frac{9}{2}$

So if we center the ellipse at origin,

$\displaystyle \small \frac{x^2}{8^2} + \frac{y^2}{(9/2)^2} = 1 \implies y = \pm \frac{9}{2} \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{64}}$

Note that the cross sections of the solid are perpendicular to the major axis. So the side of each square is $ \ \displaystyle \small 9 \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{64}}$.

Volume of solid is given by,

$\displaystyle \small \int_{-8}^{8} \bigg(9 \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{64}}\bigg)^2 \ dx = 864$

Comment: Now I got it. Many thanks!